# Why does `tr` not work with find and with command substitution?

Tags: command-line, find, command-substitution, tr

I want to transform/"translate" all files in a folder from lower to uppercase. I could use a `for` loop to do that:

```
for i in ./* ; do mv $i $(echo $i | tr "a-z" "A-Z") ; done
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` ; do mv $i $(echo $i | tr "a-z" "A-Z") ; done
```

But I'm wondering why `tr` does not work within `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} $(echo {} | tr "a-z" "A-Z") \;
```

It just prints the file names once again, with changing them to upper case. Why does the `find` version not work?

My goal is to use `find` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: because `$( )` construct is executed before find is run ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename` instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' {} +
```

The `{}` will not expand in your subshell.